# `os.environ.get()` can't find token/signing secret on macOS

Tags: python, virtualenv

I run this code to initialize my slack bot:

```
    app = App(token=os.environ.get("SLACK_BOT_TOKEN"),
    signing_secret=os.environ.get("SLACK_SIGNING_SECRET")
)
```

I picked up the project after a month-long break and now get this error message when I run the file:

```
slack_bolt.error.BoltError: Either an env variable `SLACK_BOT_TOKEN` or `token` argument in the constructor is required.
```

When I change the code like so it works:

```
app = App(token="SLACK_BOT_TOKEN"),
    signing_secret="SLACK_SIGNING_SECRET")
)
```

Why would `os.environ.get()` not work on my machine / how can I check if everything is set up correctly? Very inexperienced with .venv unfortunately. I'm on macOS 12.6

Comment: Does it work with other environment variables? Or is this the only variable that does not work? Can you test with others?

Comment: It's the only two I use so far – what's the best way to test if others work?

Comment: Are you on windows? Or a linux/mac?

Comment: It seems those environment variables are missing. How do you pass them to your application (are they globally exported, at command line, ...)?